# Can solo time be logged with a passenger?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, passenger, solo-flight

Here's a very niche question. If someone were to have completed their recreational or sport pilot license and be actively pursuing their private pilot license, could flight time without an instructor but with a passenger on board (allowed because the pilot in question has their sport/recreational) be logged as solo? It's a weird question with no real cause, but it was something I was thinking about and I couldn't figure it out myself.

Comment: Not an exact dupe, (since you don't have a PPL) but the answer to this question should answer yours:  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23519/what-is-the-faa-definition-of-solo-flight.

Comment: Close enough. Looks like it would be logged as PIC.

Comment: Solo fight time means you're the only person in the aircraft.

Comment: 757toga, by definition yes, of course.  However, CFI supervised "solo" cross countries are a thing so it is a very reasonable question to ask.  (i.e. if "solo" time can be logged flying with someone with MORE credentials than me, then...)

Comment: @757toga, and my only point is that "supervised solos" go directly against this. ;)   (the implication being that there are exceptions to many rules...)

Comment: @MichaelHall I'm not disputing your point (you are very knowledgeable) I'm just trying to focus on the exact question asked by the OP - specifically that there would not be an instructor on board, just a passenger. This eliminates the "supervised solo" aspect.

Comment: @MichaelHall FAR 61.51 (d) states: "Logging of solo flight time. Except for a student pilot performing the duties of pilot in command of an airship requiring more than one pilot flight crewmember, a pilot may log as solo flight time only that flight time when the pilot is the sole occupant of the aircraft." So to be logged as solo flight time and count towards a PPL certificate you must be by yourself. That's my only point

Comment: @MichaelHall BTW, the "supervised solo" (different words are used for this proviso in the actual reg) is specifically authorized within the regulation it applies to, e.g., FAR 61.129 (a) (4). It's not a general alternative available that supercedes FAR 61.51 (d).

Comment: @757toga, good point.  FAR 61.129 (a) (4) should probable be included in an answer.

Comment: @MichaelHall The term "supervised solo" isn't used in the regulations or by the FAA (unless I missed it, which is always possible!). The 61.129 regulation refers to solo *or* performing PIC duties with an instructor on board, so I think it's clear that they're two different things. There's a little more info in [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/84533/62) and [this legal interpretation](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/Data/interps/2014/Kuhn_2014_Legal_Interpretation.pdf).

Comment: @Pondlife, thanks for that.  I realize I am just muddying the waters here...  My INCORRECT assertion:  "supervised solo" time is used to fill solo requirements.  A more CORRECT summary:  PIC time under the supervision of a CFI may be substituted for solo time requirements.  (just ensure you don't log it as "training received"!)  I think we are good now.  Sorry for the confusion I introduced!

Comment: @757toga, please disregard my earlier remark, I was off track a bit... (per my comment above)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, solo means you're alone in the aircraft. [14 CFR 61.51(d)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-A/section-61.51) says:

> Except for a student pilot performing the duties of pilot in command
> of an airship requiring more than one pilot flight crewmember, a pilot
> may log as solo flight time only that flight time when the pilot is
> the sole occupant of the aircraft.